# Searching multiple substrings in a column of strings and return substring category

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I have two dataframes as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id":["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06"],
                    "string":["This is a cat",
                              "That is a dog",
                              "Those are birds",
                              "These are bats",
                              "I drink coffee",
                              "I bought tea"]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"category":[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                    "keywords":["cat", "dog", "birds", "bats", "coffee", "tea"]})
```

My dataframes look like this

df1:

```
id   string
01   This is a cat
02   That is a dog
03   Those are birds
04   These are bats
05   I drink coffee
06   I bought tea
```

df2:

```
category   keywords
1          cat
1          dog
2          birds
2          bats
3          coffee
3          tea
```

I would like to have an output column on df1 which is the category if at least one keyword in df2 is detected in each string in df1, otherwise return None.  The expected output should be the following.

```
id   string             category
01   This is a cat         1
02   That is a dog         1
03   Those are birds       2
04   These are bats        2
05   I drink coffee        3
06   I bought tea          3
```

I can think of looping over keywords one-by-one and scan through string one-by-one but it is not efficient enough if data is getting big.  May I have your suggestions how to improve?  Thank you.

Comment: I am really curious about performance, is possible check what is performance of accepted and my solution in real data? Because Elar solution is same like me. thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Modified your data a bit.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id":["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07"],
                    "string":["This is a cat",
                              "That is a dog",
                              "Those are birds",
                              "These are bats",
                              "I drink coffee",
                              "I bought tea", 
                              "This won't match squat"]})
```

You can use a list comprehension involving `next` with the default argument.

```
df1['category'] = [
    next((c for c, k in df2.values if k in s), None) for s in df1['string']] 

df1
   id                  string  category
0  01           This is a cat       1.0
1  02           That is a dog       1.0
2  03         Those are birds       2.0
3  04          These are bats       2.0
4  05          I drink coffee       3.0
5  06            I bought tea       3.0
6  07  This won't match squat       NaN
```

You cannot avoid the O(N<sup>2</sup>) complexity, but this should be quite performant since it doesn't always have to iterate over every string in the inner loop (unless in the worst case).

Note that this currently only supports substring matches (not regex-based matching, although with a little modification that can be done).

Answer (score 3):

Use list comprehension with `split` and match by dictionary created by `df2`:

```
d = dict(zip(df2['keywords'], df2['category']))
df1['cat'] = [next((d[y] for y in x.split() if y in d), None) for x in df1['string']]

print (df1)
   id           string  cat
0  01    This is a cat  1.0
1  02    That is a dog  1.0
2  03  Those are birds  2.0
3  04   These are bats  2.0
4  05   I drink coffee  3.0
5  06    I bought thea  NaN
```

Comment: I think they want the category, not the keyword. Check their expected output.

Comment: @jezrael, this is correct, i see many of the user even downloading for accepted answers i see a lot with me that's happening but there is no comments at all. i used to love every solution as long as they are unique and used to upvote. Downvoting is not in my dictionary :-)

Comment: @pygo - ya, the best is always comment if something wrong... Or downvote, comment and upvote if solution is corrected...

Comment: @jezrael, yes indeed, peoples are devoting their precious time hence should always be encouraged rather a unseen pinch with downvote :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another easy to understand solution mapping `df1['string']`:

```
# create a dictionary with keyword->category pairs
cats = dict(zip(df2.keywords, df2.category))

def categorize(s):
    for cat in cats.keys():
        if cat in s:
            return cats[cat]
    # return 0 in case nothing is found
    return 0

df1['category'] = df1['string'].map(lambda x: categorize(x))

print(df1)

   id           string  category
0  01    This is a cat         1
1  02    That is a dog         1
2  03  Those are birds         2
3  04   These are bats         2
4  05   I drink coffee         3
5  06     I bought tea         3
```